# To get OS and Browser languages in PHP, Chrome might changed

Tags: javascript, php, browser, operating-system

I am trying to get the language from OS or Browser(preferred Browser though).

There are some examples like,

1) `var lang= navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;(javascript)`

2) `$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);(PHP)`

I don't mind use either of them, but the result is what I didn't expect.

```
Window 10 Korean version, Windows display language(English) <= my PC setting<br>
- Browser(language version) -> result<br>
- Explore(en) -> en<br>
- Chrome(en or ko) -> ko<br>
- Firefox(ko) -> ko<br>
```

I thought the codes might bring the language of OS at first. However, Explore brought "en" and it might bring a browser language. I tested with English version of Chrome, but the result is 'ko'.

Now, I am losing! Can somebody explain what the code brings? OS or Browser? 
And is there way to get the browser's language? including Chrome and Firefox?

Thanks masters!!